# PowerShell doesn't recognize a command until restarting the session

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I'm working on a series of scripts that'll install the Chef Infra Client, then run a Chef job from a template. I currently have Script A that installs Chef and copies some cookbooks and templates, and Script B that kicks off the Chef deploy (both are simplified):

**Script A**
`Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-File", "$PSScriptRoot\ScriptB.ps1", "-templatePath", "$templatePath", "-templateFile", "$templateFile"`

**Script B**
`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { chef-client }`

When Script B is called from Script A, I get a generic "chef-client is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function..." etc.

I've tried typing the command directly into the same console, starting a new elevated PowerShell session, and running Script B manually, to no avail. However, if I close PowerShell and reopen it, the chef-client command is recognized using all three above methods. I thought this might be an alias, but I ran Get-Alias and it doesn't appear there.

I assume some update is being made after the Chef Infra Client is installed which requires a refresh of the PowerShell session, which leads to my question - how do I do that without any manual intervention?

Comment: I assume that the installer adds a new directory path to the system or user environment variable `PATH`. Environment variables are not updated/refreshed in already created processes, and child processes, like your ScriptB, inherits the environment variables from the parent process. You should just use the absolute path to `C:\somewhere\chef-client.exe`.

Comment: Yep, I ended up figuring this out after doing some digging. Thank you for the tips on directory paths/ PATH variable.

Went straight to `C:\opscode\chef\bin\chef-client.bat` and passed the arguments to that. Thank you!